# Scanning of Bluetooth Low Energy Fails

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am currently developing an application that will use Bluetooth Low Energy.

I am using the following link,

http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html

I am not able to scan the surrounding BLE devices.

To scan device,

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback); 

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,byte[] scanRecord) 
        {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {

                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);

                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: might be stupid question but is the BTAdapter enabled? `mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` AND also is it capable of low energy bluetooth? `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)`? Are yor devices low energy bluetooth?

Comment: Yes ,that I have already checked!! I am using MOTO E mobile having KITKAT android with BLE-4Version ,completely supportable. And also my BTadapter is enabled and is capable of Low energy bluetooth.

Comment: Did you tried to download other BLE scanners from google play and scan for your devices? What are you trying to scan? Sorry but before I can help we need to discard other issues than the code... because the example I posted is working for anyone... also try the code in another BLE capable device...

Comment: Margabr- Actually I was scanning my CSR8670 kit which Ble supportable. Earlier it was in central mode that's why it was not able to detect my kit but now when I made my kit into peripheral mode than my android device is able to scan my device . But the problem still I am facing is that android api shows its connected with the kit even it is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem please add these permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response but Tom I had already added this permissions still having the problem. Are you able to scan BLE device around you through your code?

Comment: Yes I am able to find BLE devices. Use this example. 

https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html

Comment: This is the Link which I have posted here and also followed but didn't find worthy.

Comment: Oh sorry. Please send me your DeviceScanActivity + Manifest.

Comment: Can you please share your emaiL id. I will send you over there.

Comment: turnonandroiddeveloper@gmail.com

Comment: hi Khanna, did you find any solution to that.? I am facing similar problem like you.. please help

Answer (score 0):

If You are using 23 API or higher: 
You have to add location permission

These all permissions in manifest:

```
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```