# Changing target SDK from 28 to 29 results in BLE scan not working

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am working on Android app which need to be connected to BLE devices.
The app works as expected but now when I changes the target SDK to 29 (which was previously API 28) the app stops getting any scan results.
At API level 28 when the app starts I check the permission. If not granted I ask for it and then start scanning as usual for BLE devices. Then I get the scan results which include the BLE devices around me. I confirm that by printing log messages.
Now when I changed the target SDK to 29 (which is required by play store to update the app) the app stops getting scan results. I am not getting messages in the logs either.

Device which is working with API 28 and not with API 29: Samsung S10 with Android 10.

Permissions I added in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<!-- If your app targets Android 9 or lower, you can declare
     ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION instead. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Permission I request from user at runtime:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //here code for asking permission from user.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                REQUEST_ENABLE_LOCATION);
    }
```

The code where I interact with scan results:

```
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
    BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
    String deviceName = device.getName();
         if (deviceName != null) {
                    if (checkdevicename(deviceName)){

                        Log.d(TAG, "Connect:" + deviceName);
                        isConnected = true;
                        mDevice = device;

//                             // connecting to device. establishing gatt connection.
                        device.connectGatt(ma,false,mGattCallback);
                        stopScan();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG,"DEVICE NAME =====>"+deviceName);

                    }
//         super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
}}
```

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. I added scanning logic in the `foreground` service still it's not working if the app is in the background but it's working fine if I put the app in the foreground.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the privacy settings got more strict in SDK 29: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes for using BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).
So with that knowledge you might need to update your permissions, see [Scanning of Bluetooth Low Energy Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884129/scanning-of-bluetooth-low-energy-fails) as well.

In a nutshell (according to the privacy version changes in 29) you need to use [`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) permission to use certain Bluetooth functions (and also WiFi and some more).

> Some telephony, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi APIs require FINE location permission
> If your app targets Android 10 or higher, it must have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to use several methods within the Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi Aware, or Bluetooth APIs.

Comment: Please turn on your GPS to find Bluetooth devices! Isn't it weird?!

Comment: They are explaining it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions, but I fully agreed with you!